# How to click on the list when it said the list has no attribute "click"?

Tags: selenium-webdriver, python, web-testing

```
from selenium import webdriver  
import time
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys  
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
import random
import select

driver = webdriver.Chrome('ChromeDriver')
driver.get("https://devbusiness.tunai.io/login")
time.sleep(2)
driver.maximize_window()

#log in credentials
username = driver.find_element(By.NAME, "loginUsername");
username.send_keys("dayon@tunai");

password = driver.find_element(By.NAME, "loginPassword");
password.send_keys("12341234");

login = driver.find_element(By.XPATH,"//*[@id='app']/div/div/div/div/div/div[2]/form/div[4]/button");
login.submit();
time.sleep(3)

driver.get("https://devbusiness.tunai.io/dashboard/my_salon_user")
time.sleep(3)

randomUsername = random.choice(["dayon.salon3@tunai","dayonmanager@tunai","Dayon.der@tunai"])
driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//tbody[@role='rowgroup']/tr[@role='row']/td/a[text()='"+ randomUsername +"']").click()
print("Username selected: ", randomUsername)
time.sleep(5)

driver.find_element(By.XPATH,"//*[@id='page-content']/div/div[3]/div/div[2]/div/div/div[2]/div/div[1]/header/a").click()
time.sleep(5)

# Get the list of elements
elements = driver.find_elements(By.CLASS_NAME,'custom-control-input')

# Select a random element from the list
random_element = random.choice(elements)
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", random_element)

# Click on the selected element
random_element.click()
print("Element selected: ", random_element)
time.sleep(5)

driver.find_element(By.XPATH,"//*[@id='accKey']").click()
time.sleep(5)
```

I've been add "argument.click[]","webdriver wait until EC to be clickable" but still showing "Element not intractable. What would be the other possible solution? Hope someone could clarify for me. Thanks and have a nice day.

Answer (score 0):

Solution :

- Our aim is to click on specific element from list
- I will be doing it in following way:

  1. I will try to identify the element first

```
findElement():
  for element_name in randomList:
    if element_name.find("**") != -1:
       element = driver.find_elements(By.IOS_CLASS_CHAIN,(element_name)
    else:
       element = driver.find_elements(By.CLASS_NAME,(element_name))

    # Only return the first element found
    if el:
        return element[0]
    else:
        time.sleep(1)
  return None
```

2. After identified element, assert it to see if element exists

```
element = findElement()
assert element, "{}, element does not exist ".format(element)
```

3. Perform actual click event

```
if element.is_displayed() is False:
   waitForElement(element)
element.click()
```

Comment: no bro, i wanna random click on random list but it said no attribute "click"

Comment: I am using it on daily basis. This should help to click random element from list. But what I felt you should use either "find_elements_by_ios_class_chain" OR "find_elements_by_ios_predicate" to find element particularly when targeting iOS platform. 
Give a try and let me know!

Comment: It is a webpage. u can access to it and take a look.

Comment: Bro, the URL and username is in the code uploaded

Comment: @Carl Still no luck?

Comment: I have added image, now tell us what you want to perform?

Comment: Yea no luck hahah

Comment: For now, the things went smooth but it stuck during clicking on the element list.

Comment: I have added screenshot, have you seen it? Explain where you are trying to click?

Answer (score 0):

```
    from selenium import webdriver  
    import time
    from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys  
    from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
    from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
    from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
    import random
    import select
    
    driver = webdriver.Chrome('ChromeDriver')
    driver.get("https://devbusiness.tunai.io/login")
    time.sleep(2)
    driver.maximize_window()
    
    #log in credentials
    username = driver.find_element(By.NAME, "loginUsername");
    username.send_keys("dayon@tunai");
    
    password = driver.find_element(By.NAME, "loginPassword");
    password.send_keys("12341234");
    
    login = driver.find_element(By.XPATH,"//*[@id='app']/div/div/div/div/div/div[2]/form/div[4]/button");
    login.submit();
    time.sleep(3)
    
    driver.get("https://devbusiness.tunai.io/dashboard/my_salon_user")
    time.sleep(3)
    
    randomUsername = random.choice(["dayon.salon3@tunai","dayonmanager@tunai","Dayon.der@tunai"])
    driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//tbody[@role='rowgroup']/tr[@role='row']/td/a[text()='"+ randomUsername +"']").click()
    print("Username selected: ", randomUsername)
    time.sleep(5)
    
    driver.find_element(By.XPATH,"//*[@id='page-content']/div/div[3]/div/div[2]/div/div/div[2]/div/div[1]/header/a").click()
    time.sleep(5)
    
    # Get the list of elements
    elements = driver.find_elements(By.CLASS_NAME,'custom-control-input')
    
    # Select a random element from the list
    random_element = random.choice(elements)
    driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", random_element)

    # Click on the selected element
    random_element.click()
    print("Element selected: ", random_element)
    time.sleep(5)
    
    driver.find_element(By.XPATH,"//*[@id='accKey']").click()
    time.sleep(5)

I've been add "argument.click[]","webdriver wait until EC to be clickable" but still showing "Element not intractable. What would be the other possible solution? Hope someone could clarify for me. Thanks and have a nice day.
```

Comment: hi bro it returns errors: IndexError: Cannot choose from an empty sequence.

Comment: Are the class names you provided correct?

Comment: I uploaded the class name of the lists. It shouldn't be wrong. @IAMMilinPatel

Comment: Can you share the HTML that is generated?

Comment: elements = driver.find_elements(By.CLASS_NAME,'custom-control-input') in this line change 'custom-control-input' to 'custom-control' or 'custom-switch' or 'custom-control custom-switch mt-2 mb-2' and see if it works.